# React-Router-Dom (v6) not working / Can't render the home component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

After updating to react router V6 my component no longer renders:
Trying to render the home component within my app, seems like the router is correctly organized according to React Router V6.

I am able to render the "SubredditAside" component which is located outside of the  in the App.js but trying to render the Home component doesnt seem to be working

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
  BrowserRouter, 
  Routes, 
  Route,
  Router,
  } from "react-router-dom";
import { selectDarkMode } from "../features/Theme/themeSlice";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import './App.css';
import "../features/Theme/theme.css";
import Header from "../features/Header/Header";
import Home from "../features/Home/Home";
import SearchResults from "../features/SearchResults/SearchResults";
import SubredditsAside from "../features/SubredditsAside/SubredditAside";
import Subreddit from "../features/Subreddit/Subreddit";
import NotFoundPage from '../features/NotFoundPage/NotFoundPage';


function App() {
  const darkMode = useSelector(selectDarkMode);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div id="app-container" className={darkMode ? "dark" : "light"}>
          <Header />
          <main>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
              <Route path="/r/:id" component={Subreddit}/>
              <Route path="/search/:id" component={SearchResults}/>
              <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
            </Routes>
          </main>
          <aside>
            <SubredditsAside />
          </aside>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Filters from "../Filters/Filters";
import Post from "../Post/Post";
import PostLoading from "../Post/PostLoading";
import NotFoundPage from "../NotFoundPage/NotFoundPage";
import { AnimatedList } from "react-animated-list";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  loadPostsHot,
  selectPosts,
  selectIsLoading,
  selectError,
} from "../../app/appSlice";
import { setCurrentSubreddit } from "../SubredditsAside/SubredditAsideSlice"
import { setCurrentFilter } from "../Filters/filtersSlice";


const Home = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const posts = useSelector(selectPosts);
  const isLoading = useSelector(selectIsLoading);
  const error = useSelector(selectError);
  const currentSubreddit = match.params.id;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setCurrentFilter("hot"));
    dispatch(setCurrentSubreddit(""));
    dispatch(loadPostsHot());
  }, [dispatch, currentSubreddit]);

  if (error) {
    return <NotFoundPage />;
  }

  return (
      <>
      <Filters />
      {isLoading ? (
        <AnimatedList>
          <PostLoading />
          <PostLoading />
          <PostLoading />
        </AnimatedList>
      ) : (
        posts.map((post, index) => (
          <Post key={index} post={post} postIndex={index} />
        ))
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**Index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReactDOM } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './app/store';
import App from '../src/app/App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import './index.css';
import "@fontsource/roboto";
// import "./base.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: `component={Home}` is deprecated use `element={<Home/>}`
https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.3/upgrading/v5

Comment: This comment should be an answer